# Job site visitor statistic quality

Tags: discussion, jobs, statistics, job-offers

In the following image you see the traffic on our Stack Overflow Careers 2.0 page:

[image: Stack Overflow Careers traffic graph]

I want to know whether Stack Exchange only counts manual site visitors (like someone searching for a job) or also traffic generated by *Google* and other search engine providers?

Comment: No idea what you mean.

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmm, hard to describe what i mean, now clearer?

Comment: @bendeg Still unclear what you're asking.  Are you asking if we track referrer traffic from Google?

Comment: Start by what page you mean (link), then a screenshot can help. Also, what search engine? What is a "site call"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok, v3.0 of my question :) Hope now it is clear, thank you!

Comment: Better, but still can be improved... where is this graph taken from? What you mean by "**our** stack career 2.0 site"? Careers is owned by Stack Exchange and as far as I can tell, you're not employee of Stack Exchange.

Comment: With our site i mean, we are searching for new employee over career 2.0. So we have one open offer here.

Comment: @BendEg so, you posted a job offer on Careers and looking for stats?

Comment: @ShadowWizard correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stats that you see as an employer on your job listing (Views, Views/Day etc...) are from all traffic sources.

If you look under the referrer section, you'll see a break down of which sites were sending you traffic.

In most cases, you'll see a good portion of them from:

- careers.stackoverflow.com These are people that are searching on the site and came to your job.  Or were on the site looking at other jobs and followed links around to get to yours.
- stackoverflow.com  These are people that are clicking on ads on Stack Overflow that end up on your job.

The remainder could be job aggregators, search engines (such as Google), social media referrers (if you tweeted it or posted it to Facebook) etc.

Sometimes we won't get the referrer.  We still show you the stats for that in your totals, but they'll be categorized in the referrer section as: Direct URL or No Referrer Specified.